# Como tratar (String) valor com jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho um campo que ao ser preenchido ele faz diversos gatilhos, beleza até ai, tudo bem consegui com o código abaixo.

```js
$("#teste").change(function () {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $("#nome").val(valor);
    $("#idade").val(valor);
});
```

O problema é que meu campo vem com uma informação exemplo, `maicon/29`, nome e idade como faço no jQuery para pegar todas as informações até a barra e também pegar todas as informações depois da barra, com faço isso? **E se eu tiver uma outra barra, como tratá-la?**

Comment: posta seu html para que possamos ver

Comment: A informação sempre será nome/idade? Ou poderá ter mais informações? nome/idade/cidade/estado? Você pode tentar usar um split `valor.split('/')`, retornará um array com todas as informações. Posta seu HTML para termos uma ideia melhor de como responder.

Comment: @cbonimini , acho que  você não leu a  pergunta direito. (com faço isso e seu eu tiver uma outra barra como tratá-la.)

Comment: @Maicon se tiver com mais de uma barra, como é pra ficar? "banana/batata/35" deve ficar "banana/batata" o nome, e 35 idade? Pus um negrito no final da sua pergunta, para que não esqueçam daquele ponto na resposta, mas seria bom você [edit] e acrescentar exemplos de entrada com barras a mais, e como quer a saída nesses casos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente usar o `split("/")`:

```
$("#teste").change(function () {
    var valor = this.value.split("/");
    $("#nome").val(valor[0]);
    $("#idade").val(valor[1]);
});
```

Comment: Testando com "master/divider/37" não funcionou (tomando por base a parte da pergunta "E se eu tiver uma outra barra, como tratá-la?").

Comment: Get index Last /. ☺ e faça um loop na string para cada nova /.

Comment: A cada nova barra basta adicionar +1 ao numero entre chaves[]. Por exemplo: valor = split("master/divider/37", "/"),  valor[0] = master, valor[1] = divider, valor[2] = 37, e por aí vai. Mas use desse modo somente para poucos dados, caso for muitos, use um laço for.